# Вырезать один абзац, содержащий фразу

Tags: регулярные-выражения, std-regex

Подскажите как правильно составить регулярное выражение, чтоб из кучи html кода вырезать только один абзац, содержащий определенную фразу.
Пример кода:

```
<p>Один</p><br /><span>Два</span><p>один два Три четыре</p><p>Пять</p>
```

Регулярное выражение

```
/<p>(.*?)Три(.*?)<\/p>/U
```

Проблема в том, что находит и вырезает с первого по последний абзац, а необходимо вырезать только

```
<p>один два Три четыре</p>
```

Итог должен быть таким:

```
<p>Один</p><br /><span>Два</span><p>Пять</p>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот так вот:

```
<p>((?!<\/p>).)*Три.*?<\/p>
```

Тест https://regexr.com/5aqc6

> <p>Один</p><br
> /><span>Два</span>**<p>один два Три
> четыре</p>**<p>Пять</p>

Comment: Та за шо минус?